# How to hide "add fax" button in dynamics 365 using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I was not able to hide the activity button in dynamics 365 instance using ribbon. How can I do it using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<style>` tag to the page with the button's selector and hide it, like so:

```
<style>
    some-element.some-class.example {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style
```

Check the element to know what selector you should use.

You can plant this `style` element on the page using jquery, like this:

```
$("head").append("<style>some-element.some-class.example {display: none !important;}</style>");
```